# Remove unused function protypes from .h file

Tags: c, header-files

I need to remove a bunch of function prototypes from several .h files, and I was wondering if there is some kind of bash script/program to look for the prototypes that are not in the .c file and automatically remove them.

This is really useful for source code cleaning purposes when you have a big project and you did not keep track of all the changes.

Note that the it does not have anything to do with the binary, I want to remove them from the code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any program that fits your need exactly; but with some neat lateral thinking, you arrive at [cproto](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cproto/), which sort of does what you need. Just remove the current header file, run cproto to get a new one only containing the relevant prototypes, and put in whatever macros and typedefs you need from your preamble.

Answer (score 1):

You could use makeheaders to generate header files with the correct list of prototypes in and either use those headers, or cut'n'paste the definitions to replace the ones in your existing headers

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to implement this loop in your favorite scripting language:

For each .c file, find the corresponding .h file. Make all the prototypes in the .h file static. Compile the .c file. Clear up compiler errors regarding undefined static declarations. Revert the remaining prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

This does not exactly what you want, but might come close. If you use doxygen you can have it generate a whole bunch of lists and also visualize them as graphs. One of them is a `called by` relation for functions and the other one a `included by` relation for files.

You don't need to put doxygen special comments in, you may just use it to be structural information about your project.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both cproto and makeheaders.

The first one works as expected: I've created the header files, then I copied the typedef definitions, includes to other header files (important!) and so on and everything worked fine.

makeheaders is a little bit more complicated/clever, as it will create .h following the includes in the .c, so no other includes in the .h are required.